# PHP DateInterval function give wrong week number result

Tags: php, date, for-loop

I have a loop that add one week to the given date as follows,

```
$db_date = '201849';

$year = substr($db_date, 0, 4);
$week = substr($db_date, 4);

$dateFromStr = new DateTime();
$dateFromStr->setISODate($year, $week);

if($dateFromStr){
    for($b=0; $b < 27; $b++){
        $calc_date = clone $dateFromStr;
        $calc_date->add(new DateInterval("P" . $b . "W"));
        $header_week = $calc_date->format("YW");
    }   
}
```

Output :

> 201849,201850,201851,**201852,201801**,201902,201903,....,201923

but the correct output will be:

> 201849,201850,201851,**201852,201901**,201902,201903,....,201923

I don't know why I'm getting `201801` instead of `201901` as a output.

Please help me to resolve this thank you.

Comment: Note: the `if ($dateFromStr)` is not necessary, since `new DateTime` either returns an object (which is always truthy) or emits an exception. You can also omit the cloning if you use the `DateTimeImmutable` class or base the script on `DatePeriod`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know why i am getting 201801 instead of 201901 as a output.

That is because the corresponding date is `2018-12-31`.

If you want the year number according to the ISO week number, you have to use `o`, not `Y` (which is also mentioned at the [date()](https://php.net/date) manual entry).

Answer (score 1):

```
$db_date = '201849';

$year = substr($db_date, 0, 4);
$week = substr($db_date, 4);

$dateFromStr = new DateTime();
$dateFromStr->setISODate($year, $week);

if($dateFromStr){
    for($b=0; $b < 27; $b++){
        $calc_date = clone $dateFromStr;
        $calc_date->add(new DateInterval("P" . $b . "W"));
        //$header_week = $calc_date->format("YW");
        $header_week = $calc_date->format("oW");
    }   
}
```